# Electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor with allowance for gravitational redshift

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, redshift

Is there an electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor that takes into account the gravitational redshift? If so, what does it look like and where can I read more about it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations_in_curved_spacetime#Electromagnetic_stress–energy_tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the components of the electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor in special relativity:

$$T_{\mu\nu} = F_{\mu\lambda}F_{\nu}^\lambda - \frac{1}{4}\eta_{\mu\nu}F_{\lambda\sigma}F^{\lambda\sigma}$$

where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ are the components of the metric tensor in Minkowski space and $F_{\mu\nu}$ are the components of the electromagnetic field strength tensor. (units $\epsilon_0 = \mu_0 = 1$)

At first glance, we might expect the components to look starkly different in a spacetime where light is gravitationally redshifted. After all, gravity is affecting the electromagnetic fields which make up the light beam. However, the energy-momentum tensor is typically constructed *locally* while a redshift occurs over extended trajectories.

So the components of the electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor for an arbitrary curved spacetime (one that might have redshift effects), is

$$T_{\mu\nu} = F_{\mu\lambda}F_{\nu}^\lambda - \frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F_{\lambda\sigma}F^{\lambda\sigma}$$

It's identical to that for flat space, but $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is replaced by the components of an arbitrary metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. It is discussed briefly [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime#Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).